# Using ggsave to output network plots using ggraph trim borders

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

I have been using ggraph to plot networks, but I am having a problem saving to a file. When I save a plot to a file it often will cut off parts of the network.

I can work around this by increasing the width of the output plot.  But it seems to stretch the network un-necessarily.

This is the code that I use to save the plot in the picture, which trims off the edge

```
ggsave(here("plots", "InteractionPlot-Course1InstA.jpg"), plot = PlotC1IA, width = 10)
```

If I increase the width, it no longer trims the edge, but the plot is very wide.

```
ggsave(here("plots", "InteractionPlot-Course1InstA.jpg"), plot = PlotC1IA, width = 15)
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that in `geom_node_label` you can use `repel = TRUE`, which is a call to `ggrepel`. This will prevent the labels from running over the border.  It also allows you to modify the elements in `ggrepel`.  I used `point.padding = NA, box.padding = 0, force = 0.1` in the `geom_node_label` to get my plots to not overrun borders. [image]